# unable to refresh on firefox with javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox

the cache in firefox is really a pain to me right now and I know this question has been asked several time.

But is there really no other way to allow `window.location.reload();` work in firefox, it worked perfectly in chrome

I've tried all the methods I can find on Google and stackoverflow but none is working for my case.

I've tried the following:

```
document.location.reload(true);
window.href=window.href;
window.location.href;
```

I've also tried assigning a different version to the js file.

I would like to see if there are other way to bypass this.

---

This is how my js file looks like.

```
$(".drag").sortable({ // begin sortable
    connectWith: ".drag",
    receive: function(event, ui) { // begin receive
        var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
        var status = this.id;
        //alert(id);
        $.ajax({ // begin ajax
           url: "ajax/connectwith-multiple.ajax.php",
           type: "GET",
           data: {
            'sales_card_id': id,
            'status': status
            }
        }) // end ajax
        //refresh page when ajax is completed
        document.location.reload(true);
        });     
    }, // end receive
}) // end sortable
```

Comment: I don't understand the correlation between the caching and problem with reloading the page with JS.

Comment: I'm trying to make the page reload using 'window.location.reload' it works perfectly on chrome but not on firefox. I've read up online and most of them said it might be some issue with the cache.

Comment: `window.location.reload(true)` should work, what are you trying to reload from server? Did you checked in `Network` panel if it actually reloads or not?

Comment: @Kaiido I'm actually doing a drag and drop function, so once it's drop it will update the database and refresh the page. but I've tried that too, it's not working.

Comment: then I think you're looking for [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: @Kaiido i've updated my question and showed my js portion. can you help you take a look on what is going wrong. I would totally appreciate it.

Comment: you need to add a `.complete()` call to your ajax jquery.  That's when you should do the reload

Comment: Actually you don't need to reload the whole page : once your request with `$.ajax()` is `.done()` re-execute the functions you run while the page loads : `$.ajax(...[your ajax settings]).done(function(){your_onLoad_funcs()})`

Comment: Excuse me `complete()` is deprecated it was replaced by `always()`

Comment: and as its name gives a clue, it will always fire (even if the ajax call fails)

Comment: @vol7ron thanks alot for your help... it finally solved my issue. really appreciate it.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for your help too.. still trying to get the hang of ajax.

Comment: My guess is your code needs a lot of refactoring.  There's probably a lot you can do, but that should get things working as you expect them to, while you're still learning.

Comment: You **should not** edit the solved code in place of the problem code in your post - that renders it useless to future viewers since they don't know what the problem was to begin with. If you want to provide the solution to your problem, you should do so in an **answer**.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116101/is-it-ok-to-add-solved-to-the-title-of-a-question for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for the above question with the help from the comments above.

```
$(".drag").sortable({ // begin sortable
        connectWith: ".drag",
        receive: function(event, ui) { // begin receive
            var id = $(ui.item).attr('id');
            var status = this.id;
            //alert(id);
            $.ajax({ // begin ajax
               url: "ajax/connectwith-multiple.ajax.php",
               type: "GET",
               data: {
                'sales_card_id': id,
                'status': status
                }
            }) // end ajax
            //refresh page when ajax is completed
            .always(function() {
                window.location.reload();
            });     
        }, // end receive
    }) // end sortable
```